# Focusing input while transition is running screws up position on element in transitioning element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I have the following code which works as expected that focuses an input and then a transition plays:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/coydu

However if I focus the input during the transition like here (using a setTimeout to make the focus happen during the transition):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywmct

Sometimes you have to open/close it a few times or even enter text into the input.

The position on the element inside the element that has the transition playing get screwed up.  This code example brakes in at least Chrome and FireFox.  If I set the timeout to 0, it still brakes in FireFox however it is not broken in Chrome.

Now with this example I can obviously just not use setTimeout to fix the issue however I am experiencing this an a bigger application using a MV* framework and there is no way to force the focusing of the input to happen before or after the transition (besides doing the transition in JavaScript which I really really really don't want to do).

So I have 2 question about this:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there anyway to fix this so that the focusing of the input during a transition will not screw up the positioning of the element within the transitioning element?

**UPDATE**

Here is a video of the issue happening.  The first 3 times I click the button the issue happens with the timeout.  The last 3 times I click the button the issue does not happen without the timeout.

http://vimeo.com/83786195

Some some reason this issue seems to be more consistent on Mac.  It happen for me and one of my co-workers very consistently on Mac.  Another one of my co-workers who is on windows has to open the element, type something in the input, then close the element and then re-open the element again which makes the issue happen much more consistently.

Comment: What I'm missing I see the same in both codepen examples. Woks fine

Comment: @Danko I am assuming you are using windows.  Try to open it, type something in the input, then close it, and then open it again and that should show the issue I am having with the second codepen.  For some reason on my Mac, the issue happens without me having to enter anything into the input.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I am very late to the party, but if anyone runs into this problem like I just did, try not calling focus until the transition ends (from within a transitionEnd event listener that you bind prior to modifying the css). I believe focus interrupts the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `position: fixed;` on .inner?

See my demo http://jsfiddle.net/YC7a7

I did change the setTimeout to 500 so it is easier to see the change.

Comment: That does not work.  In your example the form is displaying even when outer has a width of 0.  I have the inner mainly for the min-width element which prevents the content from shifting all around when the outer element is expanding, if I did not, it would look like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fkCFu (imagine in the content in outer was more complex).

Comment: Okey, ony tested it in Safari and there it worked. Tested in Firefox and there then it showed the form either way, but if I removed position: fixed from the jsfiddle demo, and tested it in Chrome, Safari, Firefox it shows nothing wrong. So don´t know whats up with your codepen demo.

Comment: Updates my question with a video to show the issue that is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the video update. I when I'm testing your demo I see the same problem, but if I use the exact same code in jsfiddle I don´t get the problem (tested on Mac: "Chrome", "Safari", "Firefox"). So my guess is that there something wrong with Codepen for now, and I haven't used it that much so can't say for sure. Have you tested your code on your domain or something? In jsfiddle I tested with query 1.7.2 and up. http://jsfiddle.net/qmht9/

Comment: When I host the code locally a tried, it don't happen as often but it does happen.  Also when hosting is locally, if I open it, type something and the close and reopen it, it happens a lot more frequent.